# Renaming file name by incrementing them

Tags: python

I would like to rename a list of pictures in the same folder(For e.g `001.jpg` to `020.jpg` , `002.jpg` to `021.jpg` and increment).I was thinking of using Python. Recommendations?

Comment: Yes you can use python and get started with `os` module. Please share what you tried, and what difficulty you are having.

Answer (score 4):

Refer [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) library. You'll get all what you need. You have to use `rename` method to rename the file.

Below is the sample code to rename all the files in the directory to `0-N.jpg`.

```
>>> import os
>>> for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(".")):
...    f_new = '{}.jpg'.format(i)
...    os.rename(f, f_new)
...    print '{}.'.format(i), f, '->', f_new
0. file1.jpg -> 0.jpg
1. file2.jpg -> 1.jpg
2. file3.jpg -> 2.jpg
3. file4.jpg -> 3.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os, sys

files = os.listdir()
counter = 0

for file in files:
    if file[-4:] == '.jpg':
        os.rename(file, "{0}.jpg".format(counter))
        counter += 1
```